# Trigger php file at regular time intervals - without cronjobs?

Tags: php, cron

Ok so, I have a web server and a site that uses php. My question is how do I trigger php files to run at regular intervals (say every 5 minutes for example)?

Unfortunately my web hosting provider does not seem to support cronjobs, but surely there must be some alternative for people without cron access?

Comment: If you have the web server (no shared host), then you can use any other scheduler application instead of crontab

Comment: its a "virtual dedicated server" I believe

Comment: Which OS is your server is?

Comment: It's an Apache web server

Comment: You can create a daemon and run it. In that store the timing and see the time diff in do while every time. If time diff comes to 5 minutes then you can call other script and reset the timing variable & vice-versa.

Comment: you have a dedicated server and it doesn't have crons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how loosely you might want to enforce those 5 minutes, and if you have regular traffic to your site (at least 1 request once a minute), you can consider:

- on each request check the database when the job ran last time
- if this is more than 5 minutes ago, run the job and update the database

the more this script is run, the more accurate your 5 minutes will be. To increase the times this script is run:

- see if there is some file that is included on every request, like a config.php.
- Or maybe you have some routing, eg all requests go through index.php

Answer (score 2):

Given your requirements, no you cannot do it without a cronjob. Nowadays, if you don't have access to a cron tool, you just switch the host.

The alternative would be that your action would actually be triggered by your users when they visit your site, meaning that, if you are sure your website gets hit every minute, using a database you would keep track of your "cron job", so when a user visits the website, you check if the cron has ran in the last 5 minutes, if it did, you do nothing, otherwise, you run the cron and you save the timestamp when it ran into database. This happens every time when a user hits your website.

However, this is poor man cron, you shouldn't use it if your action takes allot of time, because your users will have to wait for the action to complete so if it takes time, your users will just leave the website.

EDIT: If it's a dedicated server as you say, you should have access to the shell and from there you can setup the cron.

Comment: They gave me shell access but writing shell commands is a bit of an alien concept to me. Does that mean that I actually have cron access?

Comment: Yes you do.
Maybe this can help you: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Daemon Script in PHP.

You can create a daemon and run it. In that store the timing and see the time diff in do while every time. If time diff comes to 5 minutes then you can call other script and reset the timing variable - vice-versa.